# How to convert text to URL in multi line text column

Tags: sharepoint-online, json, json-formatting

I have a flow that populates a multi line text column in SharePoint. I want the fields to be clickable as they are links. I didn't format the column to be a hyperlink b/c some links are over the 255 character limit. Is there a way to change the format of multi line text column so that it is clickable through JSON?

Comment: Is this plain multi line of text column? Try creating rich or enhanced rich multi line of text column.

Comment: It is a rich column.

Comment: Good point @Vann
Just a plain text, many guidelines say rich text but if you use rich text, the hyperlink will break because of adding <div class=.. in the link. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample script for JSON formatting:

```
{
   "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
   "elmType": "a",
   "txtContent": "=if(@currentField=='','','Click Here')",
   "attributes": {
      "target": "_blank",
      "href": "='https://tenant.sharepoint.com/' + @currentField"
   }
}
```

The multiple line text column needs to be set to allow only **Plain text** since **(Enhanced) Rich text** will add additional elements to the column values so that it breaks the formatted hyperlinks.

Reference: [Create clickable actions - Turn field values into hyperlinks.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting#create-clickable-actions)

Another sample: [SharePoint Column Formatting - Display A Single line Of Text As Hyperlink.](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/sharepoint-column-formatting-display-single-link-of-text-as-hyperlink/)

Answer (score 0):

For rich text column, you can try using HTML tags inside the text to create the the hyperlink:

```
<a href="https://www.google.com/">Access Google</a>
```

Result would be like this:
[Access Google](https://www.google.com/)